# unexpected arguments when trying to set_index on a dask.dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I am trying to merge two dask dataframes however dask appears to have some issues.
First of all, it does not recognize the "divisions" argument in set_index():

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 5
      2 import dask.dataframe as dd
      4 df_201_1_2_3_sorted = df_201_1_2_3.set_index("docdb_family_id", divisions=unique_divisions2)
----> 5 df_225_228_sorted = df_225_228.set_index("docdb_family_id", divisions=unique_divisions2)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: set_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'divisions'
```

Secondly, if I even avoid using the divisions argument, when I try to perform a simple merge the following appears:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [11], line 3
      1 ####PROBLEMA: QUESTO FA RIPARTIRE IL KERNEL!!!! SI STOPPA. COME FARE?????
----> 3 large_join2 = df_225_228_sorted.merge(
      4     df_201_1_2_3_sorted, 
      5     how="left",
      6     on=["docdb_family_id"]
      7     #left_index=True, 
      8     #right_index=True
      9 ).persist()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:9351, in DataFrame.merge(self, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
   9332 @Substitution("")
   9333 @Appender(_merge_doc, indents=2)
   9334 def merge(
   (...)
   9347     validate: str | None = None,
   9348 ) -> DataFrame:
   9349     from pandas.core.reshape.merge import merge
-> 9351     return merge(
   9352         self,
   9353         right,
   9354         how=how,
   9355         on=on,
   9356         left_on=left_on,
   9357         right_on=right_on,
   9358         left_index=left_index,
   9359         right_index=right_index,
   9360         sort=sort,
   9361         suffixes=suffixes,
   9362         copy=copy,
   9363         indicator=indicator,
   9364         validate=validate,
   9365     )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py:107, in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     90 @Substitution("\nleft : DataFrame or named Series")
     91 @Appender(_merge_doc, indents=0)
     92 def merge(
   (...)
    105     validate: str | None = None,
    106 ) -> DataFrame:
--> 107     op = _MergeOperation(
    108         left,
    109         right,
    110         how=how,
    111         on=on,
    112         left_on=left_on,
    113         right_on=right_on,
    114         left_index=left_index,
    115         right_index=right_index,
    116         sort=sort,
    117         suffixes=suffixes,
    118         copy=copy,
    119         indicator=indicator,
    120         validate=validate,
    121     )
    122     return op.get_result()

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py:629, in _MergeOperation.__init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    611 def __init__(
    612     self,
    613     left: DataFrame | Series,
   (...)
    626     validate: str | None = None,
    627 ):
    628     _left = _validate_operand(left)
--> 629     _right = _validate_operand(right)
    630     self.left = self.orig_left = _left
    631     self.right = self.orig_right = _right

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py:2285, in _validate_operand(obj)
   2283         return obj.to_frame()
   2284 else:
-> 2285     raise TypeError(
   2286         f"Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a {type(obj)} was passed"
   2287     )

TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'> was passed
```

My current version is:

```
dask                      2022.9.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 2022.9.1           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

and I already conda removed dask and reinstalled it with conda forge.

Can you help me pleae?

Comment: All of the error messages are pandas only if you look through the traceback (not dask.dataframe), and this matches the lack of a `divisions` argument. So it looks to me like `df_225_228` is just a pandas dataframe.

Comment: That's true actually. It was jut due to a confusional coding in jupyter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answering based on the resolution in comments - this is a good case where digging through the [traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) is very illuminating.

If the object you were working with were a `dask.dataframe`, the second line in the traceback would come from dask. Instead, it's from pandas:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [12], line 5
      2 import dask.dataframe as dd
      4 df_201_1_2_3_sorted = df_201_1_2_3.set_index("docdb_family_id", divisions=unique_divisions2)
----> 5 df_225_228_sorted = df_225_228.set_index("docdb_family_id", divisions=unique_divisions2)

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: set_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'divisions'
```

A typical dask.dataframe traceback will have pandas lines deep within the traceback, but these will be after many lines of dask-specific errors. Instead, we see the dataframe's `set_index` command is being handled directly by `~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py`. This indicates that the dataframe you are working with is simply a `pandas.DataFrame`.

To convert it to a dask.dataframe, use [`dask.dataframe.from_pandas`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.from_pandas.html). And since the data must already be small enough to fit into memory, you can use the (much faster) pandas set_index function, so dask doesn't have to do a scheduled partitioned reshuffle:

```py
df_225_228 = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(
    df_225_228.set_index("docdb_family_id"),
    npartitions=len(unique_divisions2),
)
```

If you'd like to enforce that the partitions match `unique_divisions2`, you could keep this in one partition and then repartition:

```py
df_225_228 = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(
    df_225_228.set_index("docdb_family_id"),
    npartitions=1,
).repartition(divisions=unique_divisions2, force=True)
```